# Is this going to cause a memory leak?

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, oop

```
type
  TTest = class
    a: integer;
  end;
  TTest2 = class(TTest)
    b: integer;
  end;

  var c:TTest;

  begin
    c:=TTest2.Create();
    c.Free;
  end;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it will not.

A variable of a base class type can be used for instantiating objects from its child classes (they are type compatible), but take note that using such a variable, you will have access only to TTest members, not TTest2 members. That means; you can access "a", but not "b".

Also, if you face any exception during TTest2.Creation execution, Create won't return a partially built object.

However, if you have some other codes between TTest2.Create and c.Free calls, raising an exception in those codes can cause memory leak; because C.Free might not execute. In such a case you should use a try-finally block.

Comment: Constructors do not return nil on failure. You're correct in your assessment that *this particular* block of code will not leak, however it is not a very useful construct.

Comment: Thank you Allen, removed that part to not mislead future readers.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no memory leak here. The constructor only returns a new resource if it succeeds. You can only leak if the constructor succeeds *and* you fail to call `Free`. Since you do nothing in between the constructor and the call to `Free`, there can be no leak.

If a constructor fails then:

- The destructor is called to free any resources.
- An exception is raised.
- The constructor does not return because the exception changes program flow.
- The assignment to the object variable, `c` in your example, does not happen.

Note that the answer from @vcldeveloper which you have accepted is incorrect in stating that `nil` is returned. Nothing is returned from a constructor that raises.

You should always wrap Create/Free pairs with try/finally as follows:

```
obj := TMyClass.Create;
try
  obj.DoSomething;
finally
  obj.Free;
end;
```

You only need to *protect the resource* once it has been assigned. So you place the `try` after the assignment.

If you place the `try` before the constructor that is an error:

```
try
  obj := TMyClass.Create;
  obj.DoSomething;
finally
  obj.Free;
end;
```

If the constructor fails then `obj` is not assigned and then when `Free` runs (and it will run thanks to the finally!) it is called on an uninitialized variable which results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Would it be correct to say that "a constructor fails" means "code in the object construction has caused an exception"?

Comment: yes that is correct. A constructor either succeeds or raises.